# Hide related content on popular websites

Tags: browser-addons

*Note: this question was originally posted on [productivity SE](https://productivity.stackexchange.com/questions/9251/hide-related-content-on-popular-websites) but it was suggested that I move it here.*

I am looking for an addon (preferably Firefox) or program that does the following to increase productivity, but I have no been able to find one using Google.

The tool should hide suggestions to read more on various popular websites. Hot network questions on Stack Exchange sites, 'did you know' on Wikipedia, suggested videos on Youtube...

I always find myself reading 10 unrelated Wikipedia articles or opening all hot Stack Exchange questions. I think a tool as described would be useful for many people, but I can't find one. Does one exist?

Comment: "If your question generally covers [...] Features of browsers which are directly related to the use of a web application (Greasemonkey scripts for a web application, etc.) then you’re in the right place to ask your question!"

Comment: Yes, but, we don't accept requests for recommendations for web apps, nor for browser add-ons for them. Try [softwarerecs.se].

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- If you use GreaseMonkey, you can [hide](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/224430) the *Hot Network Questions*.
- [CleanTube](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/cleantube/) would work for *YouTube*.

I agree with Punchlinern's sentiment, that instead of trying to find one add-on that will work across sites, you are looking at a bunch of workarounds rather than a tool that is smart enough to recognize what's central to a page vs. a distraction.  Keep in mind that on-topic serendipity is sometimes a very good thing, assuming you control and balance your time.

Comment: Yeah I was afraid it would come to custom JS or CSS; glad they exist for some sites at least

Answer (score 2):

I haven't found any extension like what you're describing either.

A workaround could be to use [Adblock Plus](https://adblockplus.org) or another similar tool and block the specified elements on the sites. You have to do it on every site but I guess you'll eventually have saved time on it.

Comment: Adblock seems like a creative solution, thanks

Answer (score 0):

I have started this add-on for Firefox:

https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/block_read_more/

To quote myself:

> Blocks "read-more" style elements on several popular websites, to help stay focussed on the actual content you were looking for.